# A more standard __attribute__((warning("msg"))

Tags: c++17, compiler-warnings, c++20, deprecation-warning, function-attributes

In my C++ library, I have a function that is still there, 1) for debugging 2) for small operations.
The function is basically a very slow fallback of more efficient versions.
(think of a loop of individual assignments vs memcpy for example)>

For this reason, I would like to emit a warning as soon the function is <s>invoked</s> instantiated directly or indirectly.
Without a warning, it is not easy to test if the function is being <s>invoked</s> instantiated because the function might be <s>called</s> instantiated through several layers of template code.

I found that GCC's `__attribute__((warning("slow function!")))` does the job quite well.

```
template<class T> 
__attribute__((warning("careful this fun is very slow, redesign your algorithm"))) 
void slow_function(T){...}
```

However, it is not standard or compatible with clang.

**Is there a better alternative for this kind of compile-time warning?**

It looks like there is a standard `[[deprecated("msg")]]` attribute that also does the job, the problem is that it is confusing because there is nothing deprecated about this function, it is there for convenience.

There is also, I found recently, a `#pragma poison` that might be applicable here, but I don't understand how it is used, besides the function is actually a member function of a template class, the examples do not consider this case. https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/09/04/function-poisoning-in-cpp/

Comment: By your explanation, this is not a "compile-time warning" at all. You want it emitted, not when the function *could* be called, but when it is *being called*. You said "*I would like to emit a warning as soon the function is invoked directly or indirectly*". Invoking a function is a runtime operation, not a compile-time one (unless the function is being invoked *at* compile-time, but let's not quibble). So, do you want a compile-time warning or message because there is a possible control path that leads to the function being called? Or should a runtime message get emitted when it gets called?

Comment: @NicolBolas, you are right, I used the wrong word. I want to produce a warning when a certain member function of a template class is instantiated in the code. I changed my post.

Comment: Maybe something like `[[deprecated(...)]]`?

Comment: @user975989, yes, as I siad, that is what I a using now, the problem is that there is nothing deprecated about this function, which can be confusing. I am d `[[deprecated("this is not deprecated, this is a warning: slow function, redesign your algorithm")]]`

Comment: I think by "slow function, redesign your algorithm" you are effectively *deprecating* (literally "expressing disapproval of") the function, so even if you aren't technically "deprecating" it, it makes sense to use `[[deprecated]]`.  Anyway, your purpose is to inform the user that this function should not be used, so why not :)

Comment: @L.F., This is a good point of view! As usual the compiler ends up convincing me that what I want to do is what the compiler already does. So, what I do now is `[[deprecated("slow function, redesign your algorithm")]]`.